# How to make Spring controller be called before all request body is transferred (and handle body as stream)?

Tags: java, spring, post, spring-mvc, stream

Now I'm trying to use this code to upload parts of large files, but method is called only after entire file is transferred (into Spring's temporary location, I guess). I need to handle upload dynamically. Any Spring params to allow call handler earlier (and parametrize it with headers & stream only)?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "uploadVideo", method = POST)
    public
    @ResponseBody
    String uploadVideo(InputStream stream,
                       @RequestHeader(value = "Range") String rangeHeader,
                       @RequestHeader("FileName") String fileName) {
// handle stream
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _only after entire file is transferred_?

Comment: After client completely finished sending content.

Comment: It's not possibly to do it while client is sending. Your servlet container has the socket implementation to read bytes from the HTTP request. When all those bytes are read, it provides an `InputStream` for them to your Spring's `DispatcherServlet` which can then pass them to your handler method.

Comment: OK.. Thanks. Can you advice me another possible solution? What can I use instead of Spring's controller to operate stream?

Comment: Why do you want to operate on the stream before you receive it all. That's not very HTTP like.

Comment: I have to handle possible networking issues, I have to save partially uploaded file in that case. And allow to restore upload later...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible, servlet container always caches requests. Now to enable upload resuming I divide my file and send it with multiple requests with `Range` headers.